# Flutter Material 'Tap to update' Button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there an 'out of the box' implementation of the functionality you get in the google app/etc. where the button at the bottom appears that allows you to 'Tap to update'? A custom snack bar doesn't seem viable as you have to have the title as well as the onTap action.

[image: Tap to update screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using Floating Action Button

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
floatingActionButton: ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  child: Container(
    height: 40,
    child: RaisedButton(
      color: Colors.blue,
      onPressed: () => {},
      child: Text('Tap to Update'),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. I already have a Floating Action Button that is pinned to the bottom bar so I'll need to figure out how to make it float over the content.

Comment: bottomNavigationBar and floatingActionButton ?

Answer (score 0):

try this combination

```
Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: FlatButton(
      child: Text('Flat Button'),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation:
        FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    floatingActionButton: RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Floating Button'),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
);
```